# Cannot run python script with nltk

Tags: python, nltk

I am running my python script with nltk on localhost. My code is :

```
#!C:\Users\fname lname\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\python.exe

print("Content-type: text/plain\n")
print("Single Quotes")
print("checkkk") 

from nltk.tokenize import sent_tokenize, word_tokenize

EXAMPLE_TEXT = "Hello Mr. Smith, how are you doing today? The weather is great, and Python is awesome. The sky is pinkish-blue. You shouldn't eat cardboard."

print(sent_tokenize(EXAMPLE_TEXT))
```

Output coming as:

```
Single Quotes
checkkk
Content-type: text/plain

Single Quotes
checkkk
```

Problem is that: It is not considering nltk import and code after this line. Please help.

Comment: have you tried printing something else, after nltk import apart from the tokens at last?

Comment: Whatever i try to print after that, it doesn't print

Comment: are you sure, you code is fully executed? where are you running this code?

Comment: localhost. myfile is placed in htdocs. I open browser and type http:\\localhost\nltk.py

Comment: that's a strange way or running python code, please try running your code through terminal . Like doing `python nltk.py`

Comment: Problem is that the from import line , it is not working

Comment: My project is hosted on localhost. So i need to add python files in my local project. Otherwise i know same code works fine on python shell. It's just that it is not working in localhost

Comment: that is not how python works.

Comment: It's probably not the cause of your problem, but naming your file the same as an existing python module or package - like `nltk.py` - is likely to cause problems eventually.

Answer (score 0):

Check whether you have downloaded necessary data files for `nltk.sent_tokenize()`.
Use `nltk.download('punkt')` to download them.

Comment: Thank you . Where do I need to execute this command: nltk.download('punkt'). ?? On cmd it doesn't work

Comment: Did that on python shell. But it's still not working

Comment: It is download at C:\Users\fname lname\AppData\Roaming\nltk_data. Do i need to copy paste to the place where my script is placed?

Comment: It was downloaded to a proper location.  Try to run your original script in **ipython** and look for errors then.